# Training attendance tracking

Tags: information-management, educational

My company sells educational solutions for companies/corporations. We are currently taking over the education program of a corporate group of tractor-dealers & workshops. At the moment they work with an Excel sheet with on X the different courses and on Y all the dealers and their employees. If an employee has finished a course it will be marked and it adds up to the total amount for each dealer (see below).
[image: excel sheet showing training passport]

My question is if there are more user-friendly and better solutions for this. 
It has to be either web-based or running on MS Windows. Budget is max $100-150

What I'm missing in the current situation:

- Quick search a dealer to check data
- Easy sorting and filtering of data
- Get a form with checkboxes to assign classes to employees
- Press a dealer to get an overview of what possible sales could be made

I am aware that many of the above could be achieved with VBA but I was hoping on a more premade solution.